# NSMutableData or NSMUtableArray?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledata

my problem is, i have a NSMutableArray of 3 objects :

```
[myMutableArray insertObject :Obj1 atIndex:0];
[myMutableArray insertObject :Obj2 atIndex:1];
[myMutableArray insertObject :Obj3 atIndex:3];
```

And then, insert atIndex0 the Obj3. After that, i want to "push" my mutable array as index1 become my first index. 
I saw that NSMutableData could be interesting but i don't know how to use it. Is it possible ?
I already try to use NSMUtableData but,  don't know how to handle it.
Thanks a lot...

Comment: what you want exactly? your question is not seems to be understandable!

Comment: if you want to decrease index of your Array then  http://www.icab.de/blog/2009/11/15/moving-objects-within-an-nsmutablearray/

Comment: your question is very confusing. please explain what you want exactly.

Comment: i want to find a way to "push" my array. An equivalent of pushing buffer in C but for Objective-c

Answer (score 0):

You can use these methods for pushing objects to NSMutableArray:

1. To the beginning

   ```
   [myMutableArray insertObject:obj1 atIndex:0];
   [myMutableArray insertObject:obj2 atIndex:0];
   ```

> If index is already occupied, the objects at index and beyond are
>   shifted by adding 1 to their indices to make room. (Apple)

2. To the end

   ```
   [myMutableArray addObject:obj1];
   [myMutableArray addObject:obj2];
   ```

> The object to add to the end of the array’s content. This value must not be nil. (Apple)

Comment: That doesn't answer the question; it merely semi-quotes the `NSMutableArray` documentation, which I'm sure the OP is very familiar with.  He wants to know how you move the object at index 1 to index 0 (I believe).

Comment: What he wants to do with old object at index 0?

Comment: i think i found the solution of my problem after looking at NSMutableData, i think it's the equivalent of notion of "buffer" in csharp, and that i wanted, but ty :)